Inexact Newton Method convergence
Let $f:\mathbb{R^n} \rightarrow \mathbb{R^n}$ be differentiable and $x^*$ be a root of $f$; $f'(x^*)$ be regular and $f'$ is Lipschitz-continuous in a neighborhood of $x^*$.
I have the following algorithm:
$S_1$: Choose $x^0 \in \mathbb{R^n}$ and $\tau \in (1,2]$. Let $k:=0$.
$S_2$: Find $d^k$ so that $\lVert f'(x^k)d^k+f(x^k) \rVert_{\infty} \leq \lVert f(x^k) \rVert^{\tau}_{\infty}$.
$S_3$: $x^{k+1}:=x^k+d^k$ and $k :=k+1$. Go back to $S_2$.
Now I want to show that there exists a neighborhood $U_{\epsilon}(x^*)$ so that the above algorithm converges for all $x^0 \in U_{\epsilon}(x^*)$ and the series $(x^k)^{\infty}_{k=0}$ converges against $x^*$ with order $\tau$.
Any idea how to proceed here?

Without loss of much generality you have constants $K$, $L$, and $M$ such that
$$\|f'(x)^{-1}\| \leq K, \quad \|f'(x) - f'(y)\| \leq L \||x - y\|, \quad \|f'(x)\| \leq M$$
for all $x$ and $y$. After all, we aim to start and remain in the vicinity of a zero of $f$. For any residual $f(x)$ we have the general estimate
$$ \|f(x) \| = \|f(z) - f(x) \| \leq M \|z - x\|.$$
Let $g$ denote function which executes a single Newton step, i.e., $$g(x) = x - f'(x)^{-1}f(x).$$
Let $z$ denote any zero of $f$. Then we have the standard estimate
$$\|z - g(x)\| \leq \frac{1}{2}LK\|z-x\|^2$$
which is frequently used to establish local convergence of Newton's method with an order that is at least quadratic.
Now let $x$ be given, let $d$ be vector such that $$\|f(x) + f'(x)d\| \leq \|f(x)\|^\tau$$ and let $s$ denote the correction needed for Newton's method, i.e., $$f(x) + f'(x)s = 0.$$
Then we have the trivial transformation
$$z - (x + d) = z - (x + s) + (s-d) = z - g(x) + f'(x)^{-1}(f'(x)s-f'(x)d)$$
We shall soon apply the triangular inequality to this expression, but we process the rightmost subexpression first. We observe that
$$f'(x)s-f'(x)d = -f(x) - f'(x)d = - (f(x) + f'(x)d)$$
It follows that
$$ \| z - (x+d)\| \leq \frac{1}{2} LK\|z-x\|^2 + K\|f(x)\|^\tau$$
It follows that
$$ \| z - (x+d)\| \leq \frac{1}{2} L K \|z-x\|^2 + K M^\tau \|z-x\|^\tau.$$
We can now write
$$ \| z - (x + d)\| \leq \left( \frac{1}{2} L K \|z-x\|^{2-\tau} + KM^\tau\right) \|z-x\|^\tau$$
and this inequality is strong enough to establish local convergence with an order that is at least $\tau$.
I have utilized two results. They are well-known and elementary proofs are given in many textbooks. I am partial to the treatment given in the paper:

Newton's method revisited: How accurate do we need to be?

which explores new and old ideas for analyzing the convergence of quasi-Newton method subject to rounding errors.

If you would like a textbook to compare, this material is covered in Chapter 2 of Iterative Methods for Optimization by Kelley
